Error: runtimeTemplate.supportsAsyncFunction is not a function
I have a host and remote application developed with Angular 15.
Below is the webpack config of host:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main',
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    scriptType: 'text/javascript',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'host',
      remotes: {
        helloworld: 'helloworld@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Below is webpack config of MFE:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    scriptType: 'text/javascript',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        type: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: 'tsconfig.app.json',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'helloworld',
      exposes: {
        './HelloWorldModule': './src/app/hello.module.ts',
      },
    }),
  ],
};

I am loading the MFE module in host using following code:
  {
    path: 'flights-search',
    loadChildren: () => // @ts-ignore
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    import('helloworld/HelloWorldModule').then(m => m.Module).catch(error => console.log('Error=>', error))
  },

On running npm start in host, I get following error:
external "helloworld@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js" - Error: runtimeTemplate.supportsAsyncFunction is not a function
Below are the packages I am using:
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "4.9.2",
"webpack": "^5.94.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0"

I also encountered this problem. The reason for my problem is that the webpack version of the application's package.json is 5.72.1, but there is a third-party package under node_modules that depends on the version of webpack:5.93.0. There are two solutions: 1. Upgrade the webpack version of the application to 5.93.0; 2. Downgrade the webpack version of the third-party package

In my case, I am using webpack 5.94.0 in both host and mfe, still I get this error.
Secondly how did you identified the third party library that was causing issue.
I tried matching all versions in host and mfe but no luck.

You can use the npm ls webpack command to view the project's dependencies.
